# How do I allow facets on my full content display page?

Tags: blocks, commerce, search

I have installed Kickstart Commerce 2. I have been able to allow facet searches on my collection pages, by simply adding collection/* under the "Show block on specific pages" section of the blocks that I want to have the facet search block appear on. It works great, except they are not appearing on the full content display pages. The URL path for my product's content type shows as "examplesite.com/lightfixtures/", but adding "lightfixtures/*" under the "Show block on specific pages" didn't make the block appear on my "lightfixtures" pages.

Currently, a user will see several products displayed in a teaser view. The user clicks on the product they want more information on and are brought to a full content display page of that one product. As this page contains no search facets, the user has to click their browser's back button in order to search for something else.

How do I allow facets on my full content display page?

Thank you to anyone they can offer some direction in this please.

Answer (score 0):

So I've decided this does not need to be done. When a user gets to the product page (however they land there), they simply click the next level of the breadcrumb link to get to that parent group.

Here are some examples of how this is shown is various e-commerce sites:

1. Macy's product page (no facets showing): http://www1.macys.com/shop/product/louis-raphael-pants-hidden-extention-pleated-pants?ID=796776&CategoryID=89#fn=sp%3D1%26spc%3D546%26ruleId%3D60%26slotId%3Drec%281%29
2. Then you click on "Pants" on the breadcrumb link and you see the facets: http://www1.macys.com/shop/mens-clothing/mens-pants?id=89

I hope that helps others who may have this question.

Best,

Tom

Comment: My preferred approach (not yet implemented): is to put search results on the same page as the content. These would serve a purpose for the user as "related" links and follows convention - if you look at this site drupal.stackexchange.com you'll see related results. But we would probably want to display them in a smaller space, using a different view with theming and the view could restrict the number of items shown. See further detail in my answer here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/77985/1082 (I will try to follow up with how to implement this - thoughts so far welcome!)